# How to groupby only certain weekdays?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dateset which I want to further filter down. What I right now do is to group it by day and hour. But I want to split the dataframe in workdays (Monday-Friday) and weekend (Saturday-Sunday) and get the hourly values from each dataframe. What I want is Dataframe(Monday-Friday) contains the hourly mean for each hour of the days (Monday-Friday) and the other dataframe(Saturday-Sunday) contains the hourly mean for each hour of the weekend. How can I do it?

The actual data is in a pivot table. My data as an example:

```
datetime                    value 
2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.22 
2018-01-01 00:35:00+01:00   0.31   
2018-01-01 00:40:00+01:00   0.36   
2018-01-02 00:30:00+01:00   1.15  
2018-01-02 00:35:00+01:00   1.80   
2018-01-03 00:30:00+01:00   2.60  
2018-01-03 00:35:00+01:00   0.31   
2018-01-03 00:40:00+01:00   2.30 
2018-01-04 00:30:00+01:00   1.90   
2018-01-04 00:35:00+01:00   0.31   
2018-01-04 00:40:00+01:00   0.11   
2018-01-04 00:45:00+01:00   2.10  
2018-01-05 00:35:00+01:00   0.31   
2018-01-05 00:40:00+01:00   0.31   
2018-01-06 00:30:00+01:00   2.90 
2018-01-07 00:35:00+01:00   0.31
```

This is what I use for the hourly data as an example:

```
hourly_data = df.groupby([lambda idx: idx.hour]).agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

What I currently have for Monday-Sunday is this hourly data as a result:

```
    mean        std
0   27.860838   18.343950
1   24.911061   16.232515
2   22.336631   14.677039
3   20.573154   12.753809
4   20.212531   12.344275
5   21.627746   13.345323
6   25.588201   14.912653
7   30.159981   17.578256
8   31.318752   17.861644
9   29.879141   16.428627
10  28.352384   15.407880
11  27.699245   15.733109
12  28.969922   17.200370
13  30.788167   19.134690
14  32.769236   20.259829
15  34.660255   21.245490
16  37.788306   22.291647
17  39.799648   23.015198
18  42.112639   24.492105
19  42.179550   25.723250
20  42.504322   26.344708
21  39.665381   24.751716
22  35.955789   22.529915
23  31.320789   19.816748
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
m = df.index.dayofweek < 5

hourly_data1 = df[m].groupby(df.index.hour).agg([np.mean, np.std])
hourly_data2 = df[~m].groupby(df.index.hour).agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

Or:

```
arr = np.where(df.index.dayofweek < 5, 'workdays','weekend')
hourly_data = (df.groupby([arr, df.index.hour])
                 .agg([np.mean, np.std])
                 .rename_axis(('type','hour')))

hourly_data1 = hourly_data.xs('workdays')
hourly_data2 = hourly_data.xs('weekend')
```

Comment: The second solution looks great. But how can I group the days from the hourly_data together? The result is a multi index dataframe with first column the weekday and the second the hours. How can I group this together to get a dataframe1 with 0-23 for Monday-Friday. And Dataframe2 for 0-23 for Saturday-Sunday. Many thanks.:)

Comment: @Gobrel - You need remove first level of MultiIndex? Added second solution withour removed.

Comment: Do you know by any chance howto remove the first level of the multiindex? I am searching the web for a solution but can't get one to work.

Comment: @Gobrel - Use `hourly_data.query("week < 5").reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`

Comment: Thank you verry much. I really appreciate your efforts. My main problem with the handling of the hourly_data2 is, that I can drop the level with your solution. But I end up with a long list with entries from 0-23 and again from 0-23. My main question and goal is how can I get this long list aggregated to mean values so that I only have 0-23 instead of 0-23 0-23 0-23 0-23 0-23 for each day. The multiindex is gone, but the entries are still for each day.:)